# xdebug ignoring error suppression - scream not installed

Tags: sublimetext3, xdebug

I have `xdebug` installed and am developing using `Sublimetext 3` on a `Ubuntu 14.10` laptop. My issue is with errors that are suppressed using `@` symbol being parsed by `xdebug`. So any autoloaders in my neat mvc architecture means that I have to press the `run` shortcut keys repeatedly to eventually see if my changes worked or not. Very Irritating. Whats more so I do not have `scream` enabled. In my `phpinfo()` a search for `scream` only produces `xdebug.scream = Off`.

So... in my autoloaders the following will trigger warnings with xdebug.

```
@include $class . ".php";
```

Do I have to specifically tell `xdebug` to not ignore errors? Is there a way for me to programatically state that I want `@include(` warnings to be ignored by xdebug but `include(` warnings to be triggered?

any help is appreciated.

`SublimeText 3 xdebug settings`

```
{
    // For remote debugging to resolve the file locations
    // it is required to configure the path mapping
    // with the server path as key and local path as value.
    //
    // Make sure to use absolute path when defining server path,
    // because Xdebug debugger engine does not return symbolic links.
    //
    // Example:
    // "/absolute/path/to/file/on/server" : "/path/to/file/on/computer",
    // "/var/www/htdocs/example/" : "C:/git/websites/example/"
    "path_mapping": {

    },

    // Determine which URL to launch in the default web browser
    // when starting/stopping a session.
    "url": "",

    // An IDE key is used to identify with debugger engine
    // when Sublime Text will start or stop a debugging session.
    //
    // This package does not filter sessions by IDE key,
    // it will accept any IDE key, also ones that do not match this configured IDE key.
    // It is merely used when launching the default web browser with the configured URL.
    "ide_key": "",

    // Which port number Sublime Text should listen
    // to connect with debugger engine.
    "port": 9000,

    // Show super globals in context view.
    "super_globals": true,

    // Maximum amount of array children
    // and object's properties to return.
    "max_children": 32,

    // Maximum amount of
    // variable data to initially retrieve.
    "max_data": 1024,

    // Maximum amount of nested levels to retrieve
    // of array elements and object properties.
    "max_depth": 1,

    // Break at first line on session start, when debugger engine has connected.
    "break_on_start": false,

    // Break on exceptions, suspend execution
    // when the exception name matches an entry in this list value.
    "break_on_exception": [
        // E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR
        "Fatal error",
        // E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR (since PHP 5.2.0)
        "Catchable fatal error",
        // E_WARNING, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING
        //"Warning"
    ],

    // Always close debug windows and restore layout on session stop.
    "close_on_stop": false,

    // Do not show possible password values in context output.
    "hide_password": false,

    // Show in output parsed response instead of raw XML.
    "pretty_output": false,

    // Always launch browser on session start/stop.
    // Note: This will only work if you have the 'url' setting configured.
    "launch_browser": false,

    // When launching browser on session stop do not execute script.
    // By using parameter XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC instead of XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP.
    "browser_no_execute": false,

    // Do not use the debugging window layout.
    "disable_layout": false,

    // Window layout that is being used when debugging.
    "debug_layout" : {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.7, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
    },

    // Group and index positions for debug views.
    "breakpoint_group": 2,
    "breakpoint_index": 1,
    "context_group": 1,
    "context_index": 0,
    "stack_group": 2,
    "stack_index": 0,
    "watch_group": 1,
    "watch_index": 1,

    // Custom gutter icons for indicating current line or enabled/disabled breakpoints.
    //
    // Do not use same icon for following values, because Sublime Text is unable
    // to use the same icon for different scopes, in case there are duplicate icons
    // detected it will fall back to the corresponding icon in the package.
    "breakpoint_enabled": "circle",
    "breakpoint_disabled": "dot",
    "breakpoint_current": "",
    "current_line": "bookmark",

    // Path to Python installation on your system.
    // Which is being used to load missing modules.
    //
    // It is recommended to configure your Python path for Sublime Text 2
    // especially on older UNIX systems, where some modules (xml.parsers.expat)
    // might be missing and could improve performance of package.
    //
    // Example:
    // "python_path" : "/usr/lib/python2.7"
    "python_path" : "",

    // Show detailed log information about communication
    // between debugger engine and Sublime Text.
    // Log can be found at Packages/User/Xdebug.log
    "debug": false
}
```

And my project specific settings (just in case):

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/media/DATA/www/mysite.loc"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
            "url": "http://mysite.loc/",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: odd, I use pretty much default settings, and XDebug doesn't do anything--not even for exceptions, unless I set a breakpoint...it may be your IDE settings and not XDebug.

Comment: could very easily be. Will add my IDE settings for xdebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have sublime text, I'm a PhpStorm fan, so I can't verify anything for you. However, you should be able to add a break_on_exception configuration that doesn't include Notice, Warning, etc., and see if that works for you:

http://kerryritter.com/quickstart-guide-to-debugging-php-in-sublime-text-3/

```
"break_on_exception": [
    // E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR
    "Fatal error",
    // E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR (since PHP 5.2.0)
    "Catchable fatal error",
    // // E_WARNING, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING
    // "Warning",
    // // E_PARSE
    // "Parse error",
    // // E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE
    // "Notice",
    // // E_STRICT
    // "Strict standards",
    // // E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED (since PHP 5.3.0)
    // "Deprecated",
    // // 0
    // "Xdebug",
    // // default
    // "Unknown error"
],
```

**[UPDATE 2015-03-06]**

If your IDE is breaking on even suppressed errors, then I doubt that's an option.  However, my suggestion would be to have it NOT break on any errors because you can see the errors in your error log with a tail very easily, and I don't think suppressed errors will go there.  However, the fact that this is such a problem for you makes it sound like you are using error suppression for a LOT of errors...just my two cents, but this should never be the case.

http://www.sitepoint.com/why-suppressing-notices-is-wrong/

Even suppressed errors slow down the performance of your app...so if you using suppression to avoid testing for undefined indexes, etc. e.g.

```
$var = @$_POST['name']
```

Just to avoid doing this:

```
$var = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
```

Then, you should reconsider what you are doing and stop using suppression.  For instance, it would  be better to write a wrapper class:

```
class Input {
    private $_input;

    public function __construct( array $data ) {
        $this->_input= $data;
    }
    public function get( $name ) {
        return isset($this->_input[$name]) ? $this->_input[$name] : null;
    }
}
```

Doing this not only keeps you from having to suppress errors, but makes your code more flexible and--not least to mention--able to be run by unit tests if the Input is injected.

```
$data = new Input($_POST);
$var = $data->get('name');
```

Comment: I have only `Fatal Error` uncommented in my settings. But I want to see warnings that aren't suppressed and ignore ones that are